# how can a users String output be stored into a String[] array

Tags: java, arrays, string

so i have a private String[] teamName;. all i want to do is simply use a String output by a user and store that String into String[] teamName;.
I am taking teamName[team] and equaling it to = keyboard.nextLine(), doing this is giving me a nullexpection error. why?

so for this is what i have ...

private String[] teamName;     // contains an entry for each team

```
public void enterInData( )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of teams:");
    numberOfTeams = keyboard.nextInt( );

    System.out.println("Enter number of weeks:");
    numberOfWeeks = keyboard.nextInt( );

    scores =new int [numberOfTeams][numberOfWeeks];
    // ************** Fill in Code ***************
    // Allocate array memory for teamName to store the team names.
    // Allocate array memory for scores (2 dimensional array) to store a 
    // score for each team for each week. 
        teamName = new String[4];
    for (int team = 0; team < numberOfTeams; team++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter team name");

        // ************* Fill in Code **************
        // Read in Team name and store it in teamName
        teamName = new String[team];
        teamName[team] =  keyboard.nextLine();



        for (int week = 0; week < numberOfWeeks; week++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter score for team "+ teamName[team]);
            System.out.println("on week number " + (week+1));
            // ************  Fill in Code ***************
            // Read in a score and store it in the proper spot in the scores array
         scores[team][week] = keyboard.nextInt();
         }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You get an null pointer exception because when you are re-declaring the stringTeam array within the loop (not needed at all) you are using the variable team as the size of the array. At the first iteration of the loop that variable has value 0. You create an empty array with 0 dimensions. 
What you want is simply to assign a String:

```
teamName[team] = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `teamName = new String[team];` inside your `for` loop *resets the whole array* to be full of nulls.  You're erasing everything you already had.

Comment: so how can i allocated Array memory for teamName to store team names.

Comment: Deleting that line would be a start.  You already allocated the array.